# Why camera does not work versions that lower than api 33?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-permissions, audio-recording

I have camera in my project to take video with voice and save this in device folder. I am using Dexter library for permission check. Camera open on device with higher than api 32. but lower api 33 it's not working. I check this in debug mode that's not work in Dexter code if it's granted or not. What's wrong here?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

Fragment.kt

```
private fun initCamera() {
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        requestCameraPermission()
    }

    private fun requestCameraPermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(requireContext())
            .withPermissions(
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ).withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(p0: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                    p0?.let {
                        if (it.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            startCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA)
                        }
                    }

                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    p0: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                    p1: PermissionToken?
                ) {
                    p1?.continuePermissionRequest()
                }
            }).check()
    }
    private fun startCamera(cameraSelector: CameraSelector) {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
    val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({

                                         // Preview
                                         val preview = Preview.Builder()
                                             .build()
                                             .also {
                                                 binding.previewViewTalkerDuelCreateNewDuelTakeVideo.implementationMode =
                                                     PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
                                                 it.setSurfaceProvider(
                                                     binding.previewViewTalkerDuelCreateNewDuelTakeVideo.surfaceProvider
                                                 )
                                             }

                                         val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
                                             .setQualitySelector(
                                                 QualitySelector.from(
                                                     Quality.HIGHEST,
                                                     FallbackStrategy.higherQualityOrLowerThan(Quality.SD)
                                                 )
                                             )
                                             .build()

                                         videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

                                         try {
                                             // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                                             cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                                             // Bind use cases to camera
                                             cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                                                 this, cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture
                                             )
                                         } catch (exc: Exception) {
                                             exc.printStackTrace()
                                         }
                                     }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
}
```

Dexter version:

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
```

Comment: Can you add your startCamera method and dexter library version?

Comment: @ayushimaheshwari I just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these code for permission api lower than 33. And camera works now. So I just added answer who has same error with me.

```
private fun checkPermissions(permissions: Array<String>): Boolean {
    for (permission in permissions) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
private val requestMultiplePermissions =registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions())
{
    permissions ->
    permissions.entries.forEach {
        it
    }
    if (permissions[RECORD_AUDIO] == true && permissions[CAMERA] == true) {
        startCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code, below code is working fine for me:

```
package com.example.viewbinding

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.viewbinding.databinding.ActivitySecondBinding
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySecondBinding
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        binding = ActivitySecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        requestCameraPermission()

    }

    private fun requestCameraPermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(this)
            .withPermissions(
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ).withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(p0: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                    p0?.let {
                        if (it.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            Log.wtf("Second Activity", "All permission granted")
                            startCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA)
                        }
                    }

                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    p0: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                    p1: PermissionToken?
                ) {
                    p1?.continuePermissionRequest()
                }
            }).check()
    }

    private fun startCamera(cameraSelector: CameraSelector) {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

//            val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
//                .setQualitySelector(
//                    QualitySelector.from(
//                        LocationRequestCompat.Quality.HIGHEST,
//                        FallbackStrategy.higherQualityOrLowerThan(LocationRequestCompat.Quality.SD)
//                    )
//                )
//                .build()
//
//            videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview
                )
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                exc.printStackTrace()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

    }


}
```

I would suggest you to put logs, where exactly your code is not working. I think your permissions are granted. It might be this which is not working

```
                                               binding.previewViewTalkerDuelCreateNewDuelTakeVideo.implementationMode =
                                                   PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
it.setSurfaceProvider(
                                                  binding.previewViewTalkerDuelCreateNewDuelTakeVideo.surfaceProvider
                                                 )
```

For reference you can go through their [Official Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0)

Comment: It don't enter startCamera in my project.